# How to get dynamic object keys and use it?

Tags: javascript

I have a object and I'd like to set their values manual by

```
reset({
                delivery: '',
                description1: '',
                dine_in: '',
                hidden: '',
                hide_category_tile_details: '',
                internal_name: '',
                serves1: '',
                size: '',
                takeaway: '',
                title1: '',
                upload_image: {
                    id: '',
                    src: '',
                    image_url: '',
                    result: null,
                },
            });
```

few keys like `title1`, `serves1` are dynamic and coming from `language_id` 
This `1` after title, serves, description is the `language_id`
how do I set the keys dynamic and set their value to ''?

Comment: I don't get what you want, you want to change their keys? and update the object?

Comment: Do you mean if it is coming from `language_2` or if `language_id == 2` you want the keys to be `title2`, `serves2` and  `description2` ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I assume you are unable to update you key. You can use below code to insert dynamic properties in object.

`let obj = {
delivery: '',
dine_in: '',
hidden: '',
hide_category_tile_details: '',
internal_name: '',
size: '',
takeaway: '',
upload_image: {
id: '',
src: '',
image_url: '',
result: null,
},
}

obj['description'+language_id] = 'your description';

obj['title'+language_id] = 'your title';

obj['serves'+language_id] = 'your serves';`

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get a list of all an object's own keys as an array of strings, or you can iterate through an object's keys using a [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop.

For example, using a `for...in` loop:

```js
const myObj = {
    delivery: 'a',
    description1: 'b',
    dine_in: 'c',
    hidden: 'd',
    hide_category_tile_details: 'e',
    internal_name: 'f',
    serves1: 'g',
    size: 'h',
    takeaway: 'i',
    title1: 'j',
    upload_image: {
        id: 'k',
        src: 'l',
        image_url: 'm',
        result: null,
    },
}

const reset = function (object) {
  for (let prop in myObj) {
    if (typeof myObj[prop] === 'string') {
      myObj[prop] = '';
    }
  }
};

reset(myObj);
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj, null, '\t'));
```

As you can see, that function isn't recursive so it doesn't reset the object in the `upload_image` property. But with an appropriate test to detect object properties like that, you could make it recursive. Just be mindful of how that could break, for example if you may have circular references.